# Best way to store complex data structures and custom objects server side with Flask

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm curious if anyone has any suggestions on how to store different data structures and classes in Flask and have those persist for different users. 
Let's say for user A and user B I want them to interface with different instances of a class or data structure that will be unique to them. For instance:

```
class test_class:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.dataStructure = someDataStructure()
    def do_something(self):
        self.dataStructure.doSomething()

a_instance = test_class("a")
b_instance = test_class("b")
```

These two instances of test_class will persist and be unique to their respective users. What frameworks, libraries, or design patterns would work best for storing objects like these and having them persist server side? I've looked at Flask Sessions but I don't think I can map custom objects to a session key as python classes aren't JSON serializable. I'm new to server development so i'm not sure the best way to go about handeling this kind of problem. Appreciate any help or guidance you offer.

Comment: What's your reason for not sticking with `dict`? You can always call functions to operate on data contained in the dict since this data is always going be accessed server side.

Comment: I have used the `pickle`d representation of an object once, when I needed to store some non JSON serializable data. However, I would not recommend it if it's avoidable. Storing raw data and restoring the object (with a builder method/class) is certainly better.